# Prove the compound proposition is a Tautology:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[(pvqvr) -> (p^q^r)] <--> [((pvq) -> r) ^ (r -> (p^q))]

How would I separate the variables out into columns?
How many columns would there be?
Please explain in basic detail as I would not be able to understand advanced 
Baring in mind my key:

v = OR

^ = AND

-> = Implication

<--> = Exclusive

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: `A implies B` is equivalent to `(not A) or B`. Use this to replace the implications and then analyse the two sides of the equivalence. For what values of `p`, `q` and `r` are both sides true or false?

Comment: @AxelKemper What if the implication is like..... p -> (q v r). How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume, since you mentioned columns, that you're trying to produce the truth table of your formula. 
Your truth table should begin with three columns, labeled $p$, $q$, and $r$. In these columns, enter all of the possible combinations of truth values for these three variables. So you'll have 8 rows. Then put additional columns in which you calculate (in each of the 8 rows) the truth values of the other formulas involved in your problem: $p\lor q$, $p\lor q\lor r$, $p\land q$, $p\land q\land r$, 
$$
(p\lor q\lor r)\to(p\land q\land r),
$$
$$
(p\lor q)\to r,\qquad r\to(p\land q),
$$
$$
((p\lor q)\to r)\land (r\to(p\land q)),
$$
and finally
$$
[(p\lor q\lor r)\to(p\land q\land r)]\leftrightarrow
[((p\lor q)\to r)\land (r\to(p\land q))].
$$

Comment: Thanks that makes sense :)